# psql non-breaking spaces and spase in ::money

Tags: html, postgresql, flask

There is a program in flask and postgresql. Some of the data from the number is converted into money. On Windows, the thousands separator is `&nbsp;`, this is visible in the browser console, but when you run the application on a Linux system, the separator turns into a `space`. How can I make sure that on Linux the non-breaking space is also `&nbsp;`? I don't use `to_char`

[image]

*P.S. For Windows the number is shown as 20,000, for Linux as 2,000,000*

The database query looks like this:
`COALESCE(t1.account_money, 0)::money AS account_money`
In html using jinja in one of the options the data looks like this:
`<td class="th_main_sum_i">{{ application.account_money }}</td>`

Windows and Linux locales
[image]
[image]

These are the locale settings in postgres on linux
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL converts the data type `money` to a string using the operating system's C library and the current setting of `lc_monetary`. If the two operating systems have different ideas how money should be represented, that's not PostgreSQL's problem.

The [PostgreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money) recommends that you don't use `money`:

> The money data type isn't actually very good for storing monetary values. Numeric, or (rarely) integer may be better.

With `numeric`, you can use `to_char` to format the output as you want.

Comment: And the database values are stored in vita numeric

Comment: attached in after locale Windows-postgres and Linux

Comment: Right. Don't use `money`. The fact that the locales have the same name in Linux and Windows does not mean that they behave in the same way.

Comment: those. Don't even use "money" to convert the data type? Use to_char instead, right? Are you sure you should forget about “money”?

Comment: Form your own opinion. You are not happy with the behavior, are you?

Comment: The behavior is not satisfactory, that's true! I was hoping that the difference was only in some server settings or, at worst, postgres. Previously, I used the conversion format `to_char(COALESCE(t1.account_money, 0), '999 999 999D99 ₽')` but when the number is small, there are a lot of spaces left, and because Hundreds of numbers are unloaded from the database, I thought it was very resource-intensive to convert the values into the required form

Comment: What is more important? 0.1 milliseconds faster or correct?

Comment: Can you please tell me how resources are calculated when executing a request? I'm always afraid to add something extra to data processing, even if there is pagination, ok, but still there is a lot of data

Comment: That does not seem to belong to this question.